# hibernate search for elasticsearch with JPA can not auto create index when jpa create an entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am using **hibernate-search-elasticsearch**, hibernate doc tells us that
when we create an entity using jpa, index will be created automatically. I found my programme create entity successfully but index is not created.

for using hibernate-search and es I import hibernate-search-elasticsearch jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="dev_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/travel-service/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />

        <!--Hibernate JPA-->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
                  value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="30000" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/travel?useUnicode=true&amp;charset=utf8mb4amp;autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password" value="111111" />

        <!-- search -->
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/Users/yybbk/index"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.elasticsearch.host" value="http://localhost:9200" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager" value="elasticsearch"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status" value="yellow"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy" value="CREATE"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.refresh_after_write" value="true"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
@Indexed(index = "group")
public class Group {
    private Long id;
    private Long projectId;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Field
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    @Field
    public Long getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(Long projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    @Field
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

That's all of my configs, I want to hibernate search automatically create index when I using JPA save method to create an entity, but not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Hibernate Search to plug into Hibernate ORM, and to index an entity when it's persisted, you also need to add the `org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm` module as a dependency of your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe this dependency is missing?

Comment: my project is an old project, which is using hibernate core 4.3.8, and if I use hibernate-search-orm 5.6.0.Final will be some errors. so, I don't use hibernate-search-orm , just use hibernate-search-elasticsearch directly.

Comment: @diligent You have to use hibernate-search-orm in order to make the indexing of Hibernate entities automatic.

Comment: @diligent Also, please be aware that Hibernate Search 5.6 only supports Hibernate Core version 5.0 and 5.1. I'm afraid you'll have to either upgrade your version of Hibernate Core (which would be a good thing anyway) or you won't be able to use Hibernate Search.

Comment: yes, I upgrade hibernate version, and import hibernate-search-orm, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When enabling the Elasticsearch indexmanager using this property:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager" value="elasticsearch"/>
```

this will get the indexes created on Elasticsearch, **instead of** the local Lucene index.

Essentially these other options are being ignored:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/Users/yybbk/index"/>
```

Hibernate Search should have automatically created the indexes on Elasticsearch.
You should be able to check that using your browser pointing at http://localhost:9200/group/?pretty (where "group" is the index name, I copied that from your @Indexed annotation).

Comment: Thanks Sanne. I moved directory_provider and indexBase property , leave indexmanager property, but still can not create index.

Comment: how do you know there is no index? Do you have any error?

Comment: I browse http://localhost:9200/group/?pretty which tells me that : index_not_found_exception, it status is 404.